# How to get a row by ID in a MySQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a problem with a Stored Procedure in MySQL. I want to get a single row by passing the ID parameter, however, it seems the SP ignores the WHERE filter and displays all the columns of the table.

What I find strange is that if I pass a specific value for id in a query outside the stored procedure, for example 1003, returns the expected result.

Sorry if my mistake is silly, I'm newbie.

The table structure is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Paciente
 (
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    DNI CHAR(8) UNIQUE NULL,
    Nombre NVARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    Apellido_Paterno NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Apellido_Materno NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Edad TINYINT NOT NULL,
    Sexo CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    Calle NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    Numero_Domicilio SMALLINT(4) NULL,
    Telefono NVARCHAR(8) NULL,
    Movil NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
    Estado_Civil NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
    Ocupacion NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Fecha_Registro DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Estado BOOLEAN NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;


Stored Procedure:

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `buscarPaciente`(IN id INT)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Paciente WHERE ID = id LIMIT 1;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: do you mean column or row?

Comment: Just a single record

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour is caused by naming the input parameter same as the column name, therefore mysql cannot distinguish between the column and the parameter within the `where` clause. Rename the input parameter to let's say `param_ID` and it will return the record with the requested `ID` value.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `buscarPaciente`(IN param_ID INT)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM Paciente WHERE ID = param_ID LIMIT 1;
    END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, you're right, that has solved my problem. Now it works!!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$                                                                           
CREATE PROCEDURE `Student`(IN param_ID INT)                                                
   BEGIN                                                                                      
       SELECT * FROM Student WHERE **Student.ID = param_ID** LIMIT 1;                       
   END                                                                
$$                                                                     
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).