# How to get a single row in Mysql stored procedure with select

Tags: mysql, select, return, row, procedure

I have been sreaching around and I could not find an answer to this question. It may be very simple or it could a bug, so any help to point out what I am doing wrong, it's appreciated in advance.

I have a table where id is unique:

```
Table school
---------------------------
id  name     class   fitness
---------------------------
1    Joe      4      healthy
2    Alice    7       good
3    Bob      10     excellent
```

and the stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkid(IN ID INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM school WHERE id = ID;
END
```

executing the above procedure with following command:

```
CALL checkid(2)
```

returns the entire table. if I changed the SELECT statement to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkid(IN ID INT)
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM school WHERE id = ID LIMIT 1;
END
```

I get the first row of table as the return value like this which is wrong.

---

```
id  name     class   fitness
---------------------------
1    Joe      4      healthy
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: I tried it on [rextester](http://rextester.com/KOTL44097) and your code is working as expected...

Comment: I tried it with my database - your code is good. Try to create your procedure again from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately it does not work for me. perhaps, I should try it on another computer since you said it's working for you.

Comment: I tested again but I always get the first row. are you getting the correct row or the first row when you use proc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. after trying many different things and further search through the net. I found this link that help to resolve the issue.

[How to get a row by ID in a MySQL Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501342/how-to-get-a-row-by-id-in-a-mysql-stored-procedure)

when I changed the input parameter name to something else, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing something wrong with database schema or procedure name or your query or stored procedure in not saved correctly.

Try to create your procedure in by setting your default schema in workbench and then run it. 
But I do think this is not possible at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am actually using workbench and after creating the procedure there, I ran the proc both on workbench and cmd windows and the result is as above. the update statement works fine but not select. I am a bit puzzled....

Comment: Anyone can help with this case, as I said it may look very simple but I am stuck at this problem. I don't see what could be wrong here.